# How to update a repeated non-record field on BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have seen questions on how to update a column that is a `repeated record` type of data, all using structs, but I cannot find how to update a column that just a repeated string type and was generated using `array_agg` function.

The update I'm trying to perform is based on another table. On table A I have 2 columns: id and `phone_number`. `phone_number` is an `array_agg` type of column. On table B I have lots of ids and more phone numbers, but the table does not have any array. Its just a normal table with nothing fancy on it.

Both column types on table B are nullable string. On table A only id is a nullable string and `phone_number` is a repeated string.

When table A was created (using a query) the phone_number column was limited to 5 numbers only (`array_agg(phone limit 5) as phone_number`).

How can I update numbers in table A based on ids and numbers on table B? I want to update the phone numbers of table A which ids are present on table B.

What I have tried so far is this:

```
update `table_A`
set phone_number = array(
    select phone_number from (
    select phone_number ,row_number() over(partition by id) rnum
    from `table_B` 
    
    )
    where rnum <= 5
    
    )
where id in (select distinct id from `table_B`)
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make the question much easier to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phone numbers you want to add to each id are:

```
select b.id, array_agg(b.phone_number)
from `table_B` b
where b.phone_number not in (select a.pn
                             from `table_A` a cross join
                                  unnest(a.phone_numbers) pn
                             where a.id = b.id 
                            )
group by b.id
```

You can incorporate this into an update and append the arrays to each other:

```
update `table_A` a
    set a.phone_numbers = array_concat(a.phone_numbers, b.phone_numbers)
    from (select b.id, array_agg(b.phone_number) as phone_numbers
          from `table_B` b
          where b.phone_number not in (select a.pn
                                       from `table_A` a cross join
                                            unnest(a.phone_numbers) pn
                                       where a.id = b.id 
                                      )
          group by b.id
         ) b
    where b.id = a.id
```

Comment: Thank you mister. This did the trick. Why do I need to use `array_concat` instead of `array_agg`?

Comment: @xerac . . . Because `array_agg()` is used for aggregation queries.  This code is just combining two arrays essentially in the same row (well, in the same "virtual row" after the join.